# Odoo / Openerp - Create date on customers tree view

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to add the create_date field in my regular Customer Tree view.
Since I am new on Odoo or Openerp, I am using the developer mode, and I went to Settings/User Interface/View and I selected the view res.partner.
The following code can be edited:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <tree string="Contacts">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="function" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="phone"/>
                    <field name="email"/>
                    <field name="user_id" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="is_company" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="country" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="country_id" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="parent_id" invisible="1"/>
                </tree>
```

I would like to insert the field "create_date", since this field is avaliable on the database (table res_partner), but this field is not avaliable to be inlcuded here.

Do you know how can I add the create_date in this view, using the developer mode?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not avaliable to be inlcuded here"?

Comment: Correct. Many fields can be added, but the field create_date is not avaliable to be included. Do you know why?

Comment: Just insert this line in the XML view : <field name="create_date" />, if you can't insert it, go to the openerp/addons/yourModule , then edit the view.xml and add what you want.

Comment: I am not using an extension module. I am using the base addons/base/res modules. Do you know where I need to make this edition? Thanks

Comment: I also verified almos all fields are described on the table ir_model_fields - but the create_date isn't here.

Comment: I figured out that not all fileds of my res.partner table are stored on the ir_model_data or ir_model_field tables. The field lang of the res.partner, for example, was present in both tables and it was avaliable to be inserted on my customized tree view, but the field  create_date was not published on ir_model_data or ir_model_field tables. I tryed to insert the onformation on these tables, but no success. Anyone know how to solve it? Thanks